# How to return Basic token after logging into Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

I am using Basic authorization in my Springboot project. Once I successfully login, I can inspect the backend webpage and see that there is an `Authorization` with the value `Basic YmNyeX323G5yb2xsdGVjaC5jb206cyE5c2RzZA` in the `Network` tab.

I can then use the value `Basic YmNyeX323G5yb2xsdGVjaC5jb206cyE5c2RzZA` to make requests via Postman to the server by setting that value as the `Authorization` value.

So, my question is, how can I return this value after logging in?

This is my `SecurityConfiguration.java` file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    MongoUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/register").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().logout(logout -> logout
                        .permitAll()
                        .clearAuthentication(true)
                        .logoutUrl("/logout")
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID"))
                .httpBasic()
                .and().sessionManagement().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
```

What would the end point look like that can return the basic authorization token mentioned above?

Comment: You don't... The basic authentication token is nothing more than the base64 encoded username and password seperated with a `:`. This is done by the browser, it is decoded on the server to check username/password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();
Object details = authentication.getDetails();
```

Try this, it might be useful, token in details

Comment: I have used this and this must be working.

Answer (score 4):

You don't, simply because that is not how Basic Authentication works.

The "token" (or rather header) is build on the client and sent to the server. The token is nothing more than the **username** and **password** separated by a `:` and then Base64 encoded. This is part of the HTTP standard and is just provided/done by the browser. So after entering the username / password your browser will create an `Authorization` consisting of that encoded token.

So you entered

username: **bcry}nrolltech.com** 
password: **s!9sdsd**

which becomes `YmNyeX323G5yb2xsdGVjaC5jb206cyE5c2RzZA` ( `bcry}nrolltech.com:s!9sdsd` encoded in Base64). Which is send to the server as `Authorization: YmNyeX323G5yb2xsdGVjaC5jb206cyE5c2RzZA`. Which can use the reverse process to decode it. (Just as I did to retrieve the username/password).

The token is then decoded on the server, split on the `;` and the seperated username and password are passed to the authentication mechanism for validation.

So it isn't the server that is generating this "token" nor is it a token but merely the encoded username and password.

There is more in-depth information on [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side) on how Basic Authentication works. [RFC2617](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2617#page-5) and [RFC7617](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7617) describes the protocol in great detail.